# R loop to see if column value(s) from dataframe1 match column values from dataframe2

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

Here is what I would like to do:

Write a for-loop that checks if values from one column in data frame1 are in a specific column in data frame2 and then add two columns from data frame2 to data frame 1. Sounds simple enough, right?

This is what I have so far:

```
ID <- c(seq(1:5))

zip_codes <- c("47304", "46011", "47305", "46033", "46044")

data <- data.frame(ID, zip_codes)

library(zipcode)

data("zipcode")


data_zip <- zipcode[1:25000, c("zip", "latitude", "longitude")]

data$lat <- 0
data$long <- 0

for (i in data$zip_codes){
  if (i %in% data_zip[,1]) {
    data$lat <- data_zip[i, 2]
    data$long <- data_zip[i, 3]
  }
}
```

The for-loop runs without an error, and populates the two columns in the 'data' data frame, but only puts NAs in there. I have checked the for loop and the if statement, and they run fine, which makes me think that it might be an indexing problem that has to with [i, 2] and [i, 3]. Here is what the data frame looks like before and after the loop:

Before:

```
 ID zip_codes lat long
1  1     47304   0    0
2  2     46011   0    0
3  3     47305   0    0
4  4     46033   0    0
5  5     46044   0    0
```

After:

```
  ID zip_codes lat long
1  1     47304  NA   NA
2  2     46011  NA   NA
3  3     47305  NA   NA
4  4     46033  NA   NA
5  5     46044  NA   NA
```

I would be thankful for any pointers - maybe I'm overthinking this and there's an even simpler solution out there...

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options among many others:

#### base R no loop

You can also avoid the loop using `match`:

```
cbind(data, data_zip[match(data$zip_codes, data_zip$zip), ])

      ID zip_codes   zip latitude longitude
21464  1     47304 47304 40.21540 -85.43636
20815  2     46011 46011 40.11291 -85.73700
21465  3     47305 47305 40.19229 -85.38494
20826  4     46033 46033 39.97373 -86.08875
20835  5     46044 46044 40.22121 -85.77612
```

Or even: `cbind(data, data_zip[match(data$zip_codes, data_zip$zip), -1])` to get rid of the repeated `zip` column (once you have "checked" that `match` does the job). This option requires no additional package and is likely much faster than the loop option.

#### base R - loop

If you really want a loop (yours did not properly assigned values to `data$lat/long`, here are two:

```
# this one around your original code
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    data$lat[i]  <- data_zip[data_zip$zip == data$zip_codes[i], "latitude"]
    data$long[i] <- data_zip[data_zip$zip == data$zip_codes[i], "longitude"]
}

# shorter alternative
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[i, 3:4]  <- data_zip[data_zip$zip == data$zip_codes[i], c("latitude", "longitude")]
}
```

#### dplyr

`*_join` in `dplyr` package (eg `left_join`) is a more readable and perhaps simpler alternative (yet it requires one more package). A graphical explanation of `join` can be found [there](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, Vincent! I'll definitely check it out - do you think there is a way my for-loop could have worked - just out of curiosity?

Comment: Cool! Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the merge function instead of `for loop`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- merge(data, data_zip, by.x = "zip_codes", by.y = "zip", all.x = T) %>%
      arrange(ID) %>% select(ID, zip_codes, lat = latitude, long = longitude)

> df
  ID zip_codes      lat      long
1  1     47304 40.21540 -85.43636
2  2     46011 40.11291 -85.73700
3  3     47305 40.19229 -85.38494
4  4     46033 39.97373 -86.08875
5  5     46044 40.22121 -85.77612
```